# How to merge arrays in f#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

Hav not find a method or func to join arrays, and the "@" and "+" operator not works

is there any simple func or operator to do this

like in js [...array1, element1, elment2]

given

```ml
let a = [|1;2;3|]
let b = [|2;3;4|]
```

want

```ml
let c = [|1;2;3;4|]
let d = [|1;2;3;2;3;4|]
```

Comment: `@` is short for `List.append`. Similarly, you can use `Array.append a b` for arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use builtin functions

```ml
let c = Array.distinct (Array.concat [a; b])
let d = Array.concat [a; b] // allows arbitrary count of elements
```

Update:
[`Array.distinct`](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fs#L247) keeps order of elements

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you do arrays might be the wrong data structure for your case if find yourself appending a lot.

Array comprehension syntax gives a similar experience, yield! yields the array, and single element can be used in place.

```
[| yield! a; 4] = [| 1; 2; 3; 4|]

[| yield! a; yield! b |] =  [|1; 2; 3; 2; 3; 4|]
```